# Windows DNS Server Not Resolving abs.twimg.com (Twitter)

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, twitter

I'm having trouble resolving abs.twimg.com. For this reason, twitter.com cannot be accessed. Sometimes images just don't come.

[image]

I am using Windows DNS Server with Root Hints and DNS server does not go and resolve for me.
If I query 8.8.8.8 directly from the client, it is resolved.

Instead of returning an A record, the CNAME record returns and ends there.

I'm also attaching a screenshot of the request to my DNS server.
172.16.16.43 client's ip address
10.1.1.81 DNS server ip address(Public : 194.27.153.4)
[image: wireshark]

**My dig +trace records look like this:**

```
; <<>> DiG 9.18.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.2-Ubuntu <<>> +trace abs.twimg.com
;; global options: +cmd .                       15059   IN      NS    
k.root-servers.net. .                       15059   IN      NS     
h.root-servers.net. .                       15059   IN      NS     
m.root-servers.net. .                       15059   IN      NS     
c.root-servers.net. .                       15059   IN      NS     
i.root-servers.net. .                       15059   IN      NS     
b.root-servers.net. .                       15059   IN      NS     
j.root-servers.net. .                       15059   IN      NS     
l.root-servers.net. .                       15059   IN      NS     
f.root-servers.net. .                       15059   IN      NS     
g.root-servers.net. .                       15059   IN      NS     
d.root-servers.net. .                       15059   IN      NS     
e.root-servers.net. .                       15059   IN      NS     
a.root-servers.net. ;; Received 811 bytes from
127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) in 4 ms
 
com.                    172800  IN      NS      i.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      b.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      m.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      l.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      e.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      j.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      c.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      h.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      d.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      f.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      k.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      a.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      g.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    86400   IN      DS      30909 8 2
E2D3C916F6DEEAC73294E8268FB5885044A833FC5459588F4A9184CF C41A5766 com.
86400   IN      RRSIG   DS 8 1 86400 20230830050000 20230817040000
11019 . Cj5pDyB3gDeZKoz7wKGayWBEufG8yftAyn0FSw5f3EcVgNw0OVWsSXU0
NWNkU63apBYY0VRXY65zjxpZJCnBlMvUDylOaqIhqinuv4+Enwwao7b4
tDD+1qtQ74lGvNyZCSDFwJG/SgW0+vsN92xNUCVA8+7tOgJ0qbj/tko7
F4J98xP9iG3YblkdJxn1GtTJ4gjUrCWr8GNt1rzxf8q5ChxwXJgNqsKd
NsYtI03xEnTN9isQzc9eX8TXYfIq8i+6oSrmU8nAQnQy48TfIfzSu/3q
HkYtasqfoOGhH5yHE+edR0BrfqLyhWdrTKqgBPMY9lgqNU2ssndPqWMP nSNaHg== ;;
Received 1204 bytes from 192.36.148.17#53(i.root-servers.net) in 24 ms

twimg.com.              172800  IN      NS      a.r06.twtrdns.net.
twimg.com.              172800  IN      NS      b.r06.twtrdns.net.
twimg.com.              172800  IN      NS      c.r06.twtrdns.net.
twimg.com.              172800  IN      NS      d.r06.twtrdns.net.
twimg.com.              172800  IN      NS      b.u06.twtrdns.net.
twimg.com.              172800  IN      NS      a.u06.twtrdns.net.
twimg.com.              172800  IN      NS      c.u06.twtrdns.net.
twimg.com.              172800  IN      NS      d.u06.twtrdns.net.
CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 -
CK0Q2D6NI4I7EQH8NA30NS61O48UL8G5 NS SOA RRSIG DNSKEY NSEC3PARAM
CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com. 86400 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400
20230822042514 20230815031514 4459 com.
cKIm15Fj0qB0SMw1iNOdu4xGGHz6FWQQv+IVgH0FKRvwX9YIStHv0w7X
hgJ3uYZz4DqJSwgbfRO86+yxBjnCJOjEVsCfdktK/AxLU2U6dz4g5CeR
HSc5u5kjpW3i6sxxGZeg0rrD0+1kdfD0iBCnE/uciZW1RlP3jx2xwTeL
ibWLJoHDLCdUaNjIou5gxbTFsqpqtxVAOq4uRSBAzt6zgw==
VJSVQU3PIFE1EM9S8TP9IMQ1NLIGIM9N.com. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 -
VJT03APFIF25TEVO8L2BLM13U8F34OCT NS DS RRSIG
VJSVQU3PIFE1EM9S8TP9IMQ1NLIGIM9N.com. 86400 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400
20230823060957 20230816045957 4459 com.
cHogOtDjXU76m0gIe/aczOfQfGgttbUJSwxZlAuf962dPYpOndyI/S/o
DlMVudXqD47iXfqhDf97SeGga1lbfxm4xqqSWVGcS6gBhrBqHa/IoLAq
MhvBnX3TMkP9u+uTuUJSFGQgVskcSbj2OKWcckhbkHIg0hIoEjJkc9Vd
Tp6eWGzIzDviQUxeogooTgctqGoIu87w7w4GlOKVa3Y+vw== ;; Received 738 bytes
from 192.35.51.30#53(f.gtld-servers.net) in 84 ms

abs.twimg.com.          300     IN      CNAME   cs510.wpc.edgecastcdn.net. twimg.com.              13999   IN     
NS      a.r06.twtrdns.net. twimg.com.              13999   IN      NS 
a.u06.twtrdns.net. twimg.com.              13999   IN      NS     
b.r06.twtrdns.net. twimg.com.              13999   IN      NS     
b.u06.twtrdns.net. twimg.com.              13999   IN      NS     
c.r06.twtrdns.net. twimg.com.              13999   IN      NS     
c.u06.twtrdns.net. twimg.com.              13999   IN      NS     
d.r06.twtrdns.net. twimg.com.              13999   IN      NS     
d.u06.twtrdns.net. ;; Received 225 bytes from
205.251.199.195#53(d.r06.twtrdns.net) in 72 ms
```

Comment: Maybe something that broke because he wants to rename it to the single character domain x.com haha